# Optimization, Convex Analysis, Geometry

Tags: geometry, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Let A,B,C three points on the plane. Where is the point D that minimizes the sum of distances

$\left\|d-a \right\|+\left\|d-b \right\|+\left\|d-c \right\|$ where $a=(a_{1},a_{2}), b=(b_{1},b_{2}), c=(c_{1},c_{2}),d=(d_{1},d_{2})$ ??

Comment: $D$ is the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) of $\triangle ABC$. Also, you should provide as much context as you would for any question, even if you intend to self-answer.

Comment: It is the Fermat (better known as Toricelli point). I will post a proof using results of convex analysis!

Comment: If you can read Italian you might find https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kg4RVHH2YabEXhfRGS9VMkIKAiV1_4gP/view interesting.

Comment: That was the question all about! That using results of Convex Analysis we can solve a very complicated problem!!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of solving the problem. The classical one using plane geometry and the more modern by treating is as an optimization problem of a convex but not differentiable function!!
$f(z)=\left\|z-a \right\|+\left\|z-b \right\|+\left\|z-c \right\|$ is clearly a convex function and by convex analysis $z_{0}$ is a minimizer if $0\,\in \partial f(z_{0})$ where $\partial f (z) $ is the subdifferential of convex analysis. By the theorem of convex analysis saying $\partial(f_{1}(x)+f_{2}(x)+f_{3}(x))\subseteq \partial f_{1}(x)+\partial f_{2}(x)+\partial f_{3}(x)$ we obtain $0=w_{1}+w_{2}+w_{3}$ where $w_{1}\in \partial \left\|zo-a \right\|,\,w_{2} \in \partial \left\| zo-b\right\|, \,w_{3}\in \partial \left\|zo-c \right\|$. Now $w_{1}\in \partial \left\|z_{0}-a \right\|$ by definition means $\left\|z-a \right\|-\left\|z_{0}-a \right\|\geq < w_{1},z-z_{0}>$ for all z. After a little thought we obtain $\left\|w_{1} \right\|=1$. Likewise the other two w's have also norm equal to 1. So we have to find out how it is possible the sum of three vectors in the plane with length 1 can be zero. This can happen only in one case where the angles from the point $z_{0}$ to the sides of the triangle is 120 degrees! Thus this is the minimizing point EXCEPT IN ONE CASE! When one of the angles of the triangle is $\geq $120 degrees! In this case no interior point satisfies the condition and the Toricelli point is the vertex of the triangle with the big angle!! I hope you found it interesting!

Comment: I will certainly give an answer! But I just want readers to think a bit about it!